# When are groups subgroups of a same group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Assume that $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are groups and that $G_{1} \cap G_{2}$ has a group structure that makes it a common subgroup of $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$. In other words, the set $G_{1} \cap G_{2}$ is a subgroup of $G_{1}$ and a subgroup of $G_{2}$ and the laws induced on $G_{1} \cap G_{2}$ by the laws of $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are identical. Then, if I'm not wrong, there exists a group that has both $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ as subgroups. (It can be taken isomorphic to the free product with the amalgamated subgroup $G_{1} \cap G_{2}$.) So, an "internal" property of the pair $\{G_{1}, G_{2}\}$ implies the "external" property that there exists a group that has both $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ as subgroups. More generally, does there exist an "internal" property of a family $(G_{i})_{i \in I}$ of groups (without restriction on the set $I$) that ensures that there exists a group that has every $G_{i}$ as subgroup ?
Note : "subgroup" is in the strict sense, not up to isomorphism.

Comment: There is always a group that has any collection of groups as subgroups (just take the direct product). Once you specify intersections it becomes complicated, as you are essentially requiring that they be certain subsets.

Comment: Thanks. I added the following note : "subgroup" is in the strict sense, not up to isomorphism. The groups are not really subgroups of their direct product.

Comment: Hmm, this looks a lot like a sheaf (or maybe presheaf) of groups.

Comment: Perhaps I should note that in the case of two groups, the "internal" condition is not only sufficient, but evidently necessary for the existence of a group $G$ that has the $G_{i}$'s as subgroups. A similar "internal" condition is also necessary in the general case, and there is also a necessary "internal" condition needed by the associativity of $G$. I'm above all interested by necessary and sufficient "internal" conditions for the existence of $G$.